# Extjs Format of numberfield

Tags: extjs, extjs5, formatter

I'm using ExtJS 5.1.1 an there is a big question about formatting the value.

For example a phone number i want to display the format (0000) 000 00 00-00

For an double I wanna use the format 1.000.000,10.

The last example works - just only in the console

```
xtype: 'textfield',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        thousandSeparator : '.',
        decimalSeparator : ',',
        fieldLabel: "numberfield",
        decimalPrecision: 2,
        listeners:{
            keyup: function(field){
                var val = field.getValue(),
                formatter = Ext.util.Format;

                Ext.util.Format.currencyAtEnd= true;
                Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator = '.';
                Ext.util.Format.decimalSeparator = ',';
                output = Ext.util.Format.number(val,'0.000,00');    
                console.info(output);
            }
        }
```

Does anyone can give me a hint, where the problem can be?

Michael

Comment: where do you want to display the formatted value ?

Comment: I want to display it in the numberfield. While the user enter the numbers, they are formatted in the correct format. Can you imagine ?

Comment: In my opinion it's a standard requirement, and shoud be easy to set by regEx, but it shown that it isn't a standard requirement.

Comment: it not a good idea to replace what the user is typing by another string while  he is typing.
However there is some properties you can use to validate the input with a regexp :
- vtype
- regexp
- maskRe and stripCharsRe 
You can also use a numberfield instead of a textfield to disallow non-numeric characters.

Comment: @Christophe thank you for the hint!!  With this example https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.form.field.Phone , and  your hint it's easier to understand, to become the solution !! So I can improve my skills too... !! :)